# Google Custom Script to evaluate values and assign cell value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having trouble getting my script to function the way I want it to. What I want it to do is take 3 values, evaluate them against several arguments then pass a value into a specific cell based on the evaluation. So far I have this;

```
function myFunction() {
  var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B$8");
  var l = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B$14");
  var m = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B$20");

  if(f >= 1 && l >= 1 && m >= 1) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B$49').setValue('0');
  } else if (f >= 2) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B$49').setValue('0');
  } else if (f == 1 && l == 0 && m == 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B$49').setValue('1');
  } else if (f == 0 && l  >=1 && m >= 1) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B$49').setValue('2');
  } else if (f == 0 && l+m <= 4) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B$49').setValue('3');
  } else if (f == 0 && l == 0 && m <=4) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B$49').setValue('4');
  } else if (f == 0 && i == 0 && m == 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B$49').setValue('5');
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('There has been an error, please rate manually');
  }
}
```

No matter what values I have in cells B8, B14 or B20 I get the error message.

I would also like it to be able to function in multiple columns, while rows stay the same (hense the '$' in ranges). Though I am not certain I am doing this correctly.

If anyone could take a look through my code and explain what I am doing wrong and help me understand how to fix it that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lines getting data, you need to add .getValue() like this:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B$8").getValue()
```

You have a typo in:

```
else if (f == 0 && i == 0 && m == 0)
```

I believe the i should be l.

Also, check your logic for the value '3'. Like it is you will never get to '4' or '5'.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was hoping it was something simple I missed. Thanks for catching the typo, hopefully I would have eventually.

I understand what you are saying about the logic of value '3', and I see why it is an issue. I can't think of a way to fix it though. Time to do some more research I guess.

Comment: So I found the flaws in my logic, and fixed them. In doing so I realized there was a flaw in the logic they gave me to program, so it's back to the drawing board. Thank you so much for your help, I'm sorry it was such a simple fix.

Comment: If you can explain better what you are trying to do, I would be willing to help. Sharing an example spreadsheet would be helpful.

Comment: I am trying to take three values - [f]atalities, [l]ost time injuries and [m]edical aid injuries - and evaluate them into 6 different categories as follows; 0 - More than 1 incident of each type or more than 2 fatalities | 1 - 1 fatality but no other incidents | 2 - No fatalities and more than 1 incident in each other category | 3 - No fatalities and less than 5 total incidents in other categories | 4 - No fatalities and no lost time incidents and less than 5 medical aid | 5 - No incidents in any category. As far as I can figure 2 and 3 are impossible to evaluate exclusively.